# Is there a way to see what processes are running? linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Is there a way to see what processes are running? linux
like npm servers, etc.
Sorry 4 a stupid question

Comment: On the command line, there is `ps -efl | less`, or there is also a GUI `System Monitor`.

Comment: Please spend a few minutes looking for an answer before asking a question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal:

- `ps -eaf`
- `top` (to list those with the more CPU/RAM...)

Otherwise plenty of GUI apps, depending on your desktop (try Ctrl-Esc).

Answer (score 0):

The standard commands are `ps` (perhaps in combination with `grep`) and `top`, like it was already mentioned.

I found [htop](https://hisham.hm/htop/) quite useful, which is an additional piece of software.